# Determining the unitary D uniquely from the constraint $D^TMD=M$ with diagonal $M$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

**I've made an edit to this question and title.**

Consider a **unitary** matrix $D$ which satisfy the relation $$D^TMD=M$$ where $M$ is a **diagonal** matrix with **non-zero** diagonal elements $m_1,m_2,m_3$.

I'm trying to prove that D is diagonal and its elements are $D_{ij}=\pm \delta_{ij}$ provided $m_1\neq m_2\neq m_3$.

Assume $$D=\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\\ e & f & g\\p & q & r\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$M=\begin{pmatrix}m_1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & m_2 & 0\\0 & 0 & m_3\end{pmatrix}.$$

Since $D$ is unitary $D^\dagger D=DD^\dagger=I$. Therefore, $$MD=D^*M$$ which gives $$a=a^*,b=b^*\frac{m_2}{m_1}, c=c^*\frac{m_3}{m_1}$$ and so on.

I think, I have exhausted all the conditions on D. But I'm not being able to show that the off-diagonal elements are zero and diagonal elements are $\pm 1$.

Comment: Would you please put what the book says inside a block quote? I find it difficult to tell which parts come from the book and which parts are your thoughts. The last sentence is confusing too, as diagonal elements are not necessarily eigenvalues.

Comment: @user1551 Since M is diagonal, its eigenvalues are same as its diagonal elements. Isn't it?

Comment: It might help if you provided the title of the book and page where you found this statement.

Comment: @SRS I see. Thanks.

Comment: The statement seems a little backward: If the eigenvalues of $M$ are non-degenerate then $D^T M D = M$ implies that $D$ must be diagonal. However, if they are not, $D$ could be non-diagonal. Consider the extreme case $M=I$, then $D^T M D = M$ reduces to $D^T D = I$, which can be satisfied for a non-diagonal (unitary) $D$. Maybe that is what was meant?

Comment: @all I have edited the question. Previous version was based on false understanding of the problem.

Comment: Makes more sense this way. I tried to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't particularly matter what the eigenvalues/diagonal entries of $M$ are since $D$ is constrained to be unitary.  What this means in particular is that since $D^TD = D^2 = I$, we have that $D$ is its own inverse and therefore has full rank.  The unitary and diagonal conditions force all the diagonal entries of $D$ to be $\pm1$.  If in general we assume a diagonal entry is of the form $a + bi$ we must have that

$$
(a + bi)^2 \;\; =\;\; (a^2 - b^2) + 2ab i \;\; =\;\; 1
$$

meaning that either $a$ or $b$ are zero but not both.  If $b=0$ we simply have $a = \pm 1$.  If $a =0$ we then have that $b = \pm i$ and the diagonal entry is $bi = \pm i^2 = \mp 1$.

Actually under further inspection this is simpler (assuming complex entries).  Simply having the unitary condition means $D^*D = DD^* = I$, which means that a diagonal entry must satisfy $\overline{d_{ii}} = d_{ii}$ which means the diagonal entries must be real, and $d_{ii}^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let my first answer assuming the problem is entirely real-valued.

From $D^T M D = M$ and $D D^T = I$ (due to unitarity) we can conclude $M D = D M$ (multiply $D$ from the left). In element-wise notation this reads as  $$m_j d_{i,j} = d_{i,j} m_i$$ for $i,j=1,2,\ldots,n$. Note that we can write this as $$d_{i,j}(m_j - m_i) = 0.$$ If $m_j \neq m_i$ for all $j\neq i$ this implies $d_{i,j} = 0 \; \forall \; i \neq j$. Therefore, $D$ is diagonal $ D = {\rm diag}\{d_{11}, \ldots, d_{nn}\}$. From the unitarity of $D$ it follows that $d_{ii}^2 = 1$. Collecting the results we have $D_{ij} = \pm \delta_{ij}$.

**edit**: In the complex-valued case, it depends on your notion of $D^T$. If it means conjugate transpose then from $D^T M D = M$ we again get $M D = D M$ which leads to $d_{i,j} = 0 \, \forall i \neq j$. For $d_{i,i}$ from the unitarity constraint we get $|d_{i,i}|^2 = 1$ which means $d_{i,i} = {\rm e}^{\jmath \varphi_i}$ where $\varphi_i$ is arbitrary. This means your claim is not really true (partially, the diagonality is true but the $\pm \delta_{i,j}$ fails).

If it is just a transpose then the diagonality fails as well. Here is a counterexample:

$$D = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \jmath & 0 \\
\jmath & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}.$$
As you can easily verify, $DD^\dagger=I$ (i.e., $D$ is unitary) and $D^T M D = M$.

Comment: Dear @Florian Thanks. Though my D matrix is complex ans M is real.

Comment: In the complex-valued case your claim is not true. I have augmented my answer accordingly.

Comment: In the complex case, I think $MD=D^*M$ due to the fact that $D^\dagger D=DD^\dagger=I$ @Florian

Comment: Yes, this is true. That's how I created my counter-example. Element-wise this means $m_j d_{i,j} = d_{i,j}^* m_i$. Clearly, for $m_j \neq m_i$ this can be satisfied even for $d_{i,j} \neq 0$, e.g., using $(-1) \cdot \jmath = (\jmath)^* \cdot 1$. In general, in this case the real part of $D$ needs to be zero off-diagonal, the imaginary part does not.