# Unitary matrix that commutes with a diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix and let $U$ be a unitary matrix such that $U$ commutes with $D$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
UD = DU \qquad \text{or} \qquad UDU^\dagger = D.
\end{equation}

What properties must $U$ have?

Comment: From another post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082943/determining-the-unitary-d-uniquely-from-the-constraint-dtmd-m-with-diagonal?rq=1 it seems that the unitary matrix must be diagonal if all eigenvalues are distinct. If we have degenerate eigenvalues then I guess the unitary must be block diagonal. Are there any other conditions on this block diagonal matrix?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. We may assume (up to an orthonormal change of basis -in fact, a permutaton-) that $D=diag(\lambda_1I_{i_1},\cdots,\lambda_kI_{i_k})$ where the $(\lambda_i)$ are distinct.

Then $UD=DU$ IFF $U=diag(U_1,\cdots,U_k)$ where the $(U_i)$ are unitary.